# I can't figure out the syntax issue with my statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I started learning mysql for a week and I was just trying to solve questions in LeetCode
I tried writing this for the nth highest number but i keep getting a syntax error.I can't figure out.
It will be great if someone could take a look.Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT N-1,1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` cannot accept expressions. It only accepts integers.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html:

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be
> nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Comment: So I can't put variables in there?

Comment: Then what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Calculate `N-1` before putting it in your SQL query, and use the integer value result of that expression. I assume `N` is some application variable, right?

Comment: Sir https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/ this is the question

Comment: N is the parameter of the function Sir

Comment: `N` is just an expression, but when used in the program implementation it needs to be a concrete integer.

Comment: The documentation I quoted above says you can use routine variables if they are integers. Can you think of a way to change the value of a variable?

Comment: Sir im pretty new at this.Can you help me out on how to fix this? :D